# Kendo filter unexpected behaviour

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to set filter column to be `multi` and search operator to be `contains`. Unfortunately, the filter makes a request with the `equals` operator instead. My Kendo version is 2015.3.930. My column configuration object looks like this:

```
filterable: {
  operator: "contains", 
  multi: true,
  dataSource: {
    transport: {
      read: filterReadMethod
    }
  }
}
```

What I want is a column filter (in grid) that contains chechboxes and filter by `contains`. Any suggestions?

What I've already tried:

```
cell: {
  showOperators: false,
  operator: "contains"
},
```

And

```
operators: {
  string: {
    contains: "Contains"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check out this example on the Kendo API reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-filterable.operators.string.contains). I think your code needs to be like:

```
filterable: {
    multi: true,
    operators: {
        string: {
            contains: "Contains"
        }
    }
},
```

**UPDATE**

After a bit of testing, I am going to say that no. No you cannot use both multi and contains. It appears that by setting `multi: true`, under-the-hood Kendo creates filter with the operator set to `eq`. The `change` event of the datasource actually let's you peek under the hood, but even manually setting the value does not work.

I tested in the [Kendo Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/iTupu). The code I ended up with is below. By looking at the [Kendo datasource reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-filter.filters), you can see that there are some ways to get to the filters that are being used.

So let me qualify my definitive "no" by saying that it is JavaScript and there is certainly a "hacky" way to get around this.

However, if this is really a feature that you need, then I would recommend hitting up the support forums on Telerik's site. Even if you no longer have a valid contract, they are pretty cool about answering simple questions, albeit it will be a few days before they get to it.

Wish I had a better answer for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [ {
    field: "country",
    filterable: {
      multi:true,
      search: true,
      dataSource: [ 
        { country: "BG" }, 
        { country: "USA" }
      ]
    },
  } ],
  filterable: true,
  dataSource: {
    data: [ 
      { country: "BG" }, 
      { country: "USA" }, 
      { country: "1BG3" }, 
      { country: "1USA4" } 
    ],
    /*filter: {
      logic: "or", 
      filters: [
        { field: "country", operator: "contains", value: "BG" }
      ]
    },*/
    change: function(e) {
      try{
        //e.sender._filter.filters[0].operator = "contains";
        this.filter().filters[0].operator = "contains";
        var f = this.filter().filters[0].value;
        console.log(f);
      }catch(e1) { 
        console.log(e1);
      }
    }
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention it , but i've tried this without success .. I trying it again right now .. and again nothing happens.. the filter continues to work with eq (equal)

Comment: Add this to my question to be more clear .. Thank you for your help

Comment: @HarryBirimirski have you tried setting this on the individual columns as opposed to the whole grid?

Comment: @HarryBirimirski Please see my update. I am afraid that what you want to do is not supported out of the box. `multi: true` assumes `operator: 'eq'`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time .. I'll overwrite filter in kendo.data.transports["odata-v4"].parameterMap(options.data, "read") and this will do the trick .. I was hoping to have a better way ..